# Checking if an Oracle BPEL Polling DB Adapter is working

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, soa, bpel

I have deployed a Oracle SOA composite from JDeveloper 11g with a BPEL Polling DB Adapter to Weblogic 11g.  I am trying to tell if it is working.  I am looking in the soa_server1-diagnostic.log and I see the following message:

```
[2014-10-08T14:53:02.753-05:00] [soa_server1] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.soa.adapter] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: weblogic] [ecid: b4de9447a6405836:356834d:148f023a253:-8000-00000000000002ad,1:21897] [APP: soa-infra] JCABinding=>  [NotificationService.SugarCRM_Poll/2.0] :init Successfully initialized SugarCRM_Poll_db.jca
```

First am I looking in the right log? And is this what I should see every time it runs?
The jca file for the polling DB Adapter looks like this:

```
<adapter-config name="SugarCRM_Poll" adapter="Database Adapter" wsdlLocation="SugarCRM_Poll.wsdl" xmlns="http://platform.integration.oracle/blocks/adapter/fw/metadata">

  <connection-factory location="eis/DB/SugarDbProd" UIConnectionName="SugarDbProd" adapterRef=""/>
  <endpoint-activation portType="SugarCRM_Poll_ptt" operation="receive">
    <activation-spec className="oracle.tip.adapter.db.DBActivationSpec">
      <property name="DescriptorName" value="SugarCRM_Poll.OpportunityStagingTable"/>
      <property name="QueryName" value="SugarCRM_PollSelect"/>
      <property name="MappingsMetaDataURL" value="SugarCRM_Poll-or-mappings.xml"/>
      <property name="PollingStrategy" value="LogicalDeletePollingStrategy"/>
      <property name="MarkReadColumn" value="account_name_new"/>
      <property name="MarkReadValue" value="X"/>
      <property name="MarkUnreadValue" value="R"/>
      <property name="PollingInterval" value="5"/>
      <property name="MaxRaiseSize" value="1"/>
      <property name="MaxTransactionSize" value="10"/>
      <property name="NumberOfThreads" value="1"/>
      <property name="ReturnSingleResultSet" value="false"/>
    </activation-spec>
  </endpoint-activation>


</adapter-config>
```

I am also seeing this Notification in the soa_server1-diagnostic.log:

```
[2014-10-10T07:31:05.328-05:00] [soa_server1] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.soa.adapter] [tid: Workmanager: , Version: 0, Scheduled=false, Started=false, Wait time: 0 ms\n] [userId: weblogic] [ecid: b4de9447a6405836:356834d:148f023a253:-8000-0000000000000708,1:19750] [APP: soa-infra] Database Adapter NotificationService <oracle.tip.adapter.db.InboundWork handleException> BINDING.JCA-11624[[
DBActivationSpec Polling Exception.
Query name: [SugarCRM_PollSelect], Descriptor name: [SugarCRM_Poll.OpportunityStagingTable]. Polling the database for events failed on this iteration.
Caused by com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed..
  This exception is considered retriable, likely due to a communication failure.  To classify it as non-retriable instead add property nonRetriableErrorCodes with value "0" to your deployment descriptor (i.e. weblogic-ra.xml).  Polling will be attempted again next polling interval.
```

I am able to test the connection in Weblogic 11g Admin Console and it works fine.  I see the following message : "Test of TestSugarDataSource on server soa_server1 was successful."  And I was also able to use the netcat command to to test connectivity with success. "nc -vz xx.xx.xx.xx 3306" returns a "Connection to xx.xx.xx.xx 3306 port [tcp/mysql] succeeded!"  So it appears the connectivity is not an issue.

Thanks,

Tom Henricksen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find the issue with the polling by changing the Log Configuration on the oracle.soa to TRACE:32 FINEST logging.  This allowed me to see the underlying query that was running for the Polling DB Adapter and make corrections.  The diagnostic log file gave me everything I needed once I made this change and corrected the testing.

Thanks,

Tom